# Unsuccess to send a HTML request by AsyncTask

Tags: php, android, webserver, android-asynctask, server-side

I am trying to use an AsyncTask class to send a HTML request to a backend server php file, however, the send action cannot be done, some error messages appear in the logcat, may I ask for some advices to solve the problem?

Below is my AsyncTask class:

```
private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    //private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public GrabURL() { 
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
        //Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Reader.this); 
    } 

    protected void onPreExecute(String key, String value) {
        mTest.append("PreExecute");
        //Dialog.setMessage("Sending value..");
        //Dialog.show();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key,value));
        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            mTest.append("doinback");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            client.execute(post); 
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        mTest.append("PostExecute");
        //Dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I start the send action by calling this in the outer class

```
grab.execute(new String[]{"http://192.168.1.150/myapp/check.php"});
```

No error messages are shown if I hide those things related to dialog, however, it still cannot communicate with the server.

And here are error messages if I dont hide them

```
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555): Activity android.reader.Reader has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@416dddc8 that was originally added here
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity android.reader.Reader has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@416dddc8 that was originally added here
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.reader.Reader$GrabURL.onPreExecute(Reader.java:228)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.reader.Reader$1.onClick(Reader.java:102)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-19 15:11:29.360: E/WindowManager(26555):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the code of my server side program, just a simple php file.

```
<?php
    $file = "C:/wamp/www/myapp/file.txt";
    $data = "AID:".$_POST['A']." BID:".$_POST['B'];
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

Comment: the reason of `window leadked error`. your dialog does not get `dismissed`. You do it in `onPostExecute`. But your code never goes in `onPostExecute`. There is a error in your `doInBackground`.I think you need to add breakpoints..where things are going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I have just finished my lunch, may I ask how can i add a breakpoint?

Comment: based on what you said, I try to hide all of the dialog related stuffs, those error messages red in color disappear then, however, my backend server still gives no respond to it, also there are some error messages in orange color.

Comment: this is you server side problem..on which I have no knowledge...:)I suggest you to write you server side Implemention here and change queston's tags so that  appropriate persons responds to your question.

Comment: I have updated the question a little bit, see if it can help you to recognize my problem, okay I will post the server side code also

Comment: your php script looks right. did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest file?

Comment: Ya, I have added it, so I am thinking whether it is the problem about the server, actually, my server is plced in a virtual machine, both my laptop, the server and the mobile device are in the same wifi network, but when I try to access the page in the virtual machine from my laptop, I am not able to do so by typing the IP address in

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. its your server error. I think the post is not working as it has to be.
Please check it and then put it in to AsyncTask.

Comment: actually, my server program is placed in a virtual machine, I don't know if it matters. Both the device and the machine is connecting to the same Wifi network, so I suppose it should be okay to connect to the server with the virtual address

Comment: Ok so please check it first that whether your server gives response correctly or not. then try to implement it.

Comment: I have tried to access a simple page I created in the server, however, the browser cannot get the page, I dont have idea what is the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

according to the log, execution stops at `Dialog.show()` in `preExecute()`, you dont know if there is anything wrong with your logic yet, `doInBackground()` is never executed.

try this:

- make the initializations inside a constructor
- make sure `Reader` is the name of the activity you are calling `GrabURL` in.

  ```
  private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

  ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
  private ProgressDialog Dialog;

  public void GrabURL() {
      nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Reader.this);
  }

  protected void onPreExecute(String key, String value) {
      System.out.println("PreExecute");
      Dialog.setMessage("Sending value..");
      Dialog.show();
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {
          System.out.println("doinback");
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
          UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                  nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);
          post.setEntity(ent);
          client.execute(post);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
      System.out.println("PostExecute");
      Dialog.dismiss();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value updated",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: ya, Reader is my activity class, grab object is declared in this class, and I have a button, the send event should start when the button being clicked, but it does not do so

Comment: ya, therefore I have updated my code like above and renew the error messages it returns to the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems that you are trying to update UI from `doInBackground()` by executing `mTest.append("doinback");` which seems to be a TextView. So, remove that and better try to update UI elements from `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: oh, ya, I forgot to remove it, initially i want to check if the program has entered the function, so I added it. Thankyou for remaining!